# Close bootstrap modal after submit and return to parent file dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 php files (student.php, teacher.php, coordinator.php) which loads a common form addlastname.php (external file) into a bootstrap modal on click of a button.

**Link to External form file:**

```
<a href="addlastname.php" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

This form file inserts data into db on submit action

**Form file body:** (addlastname.php)

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h1 class="modal-title text-center">Add new last name</h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction;?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">           
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="text" name="LastName" value="" size="32" class="form-control"/>
        <p class="">The first alphabet of the last name <strong>MUST</strong> be in upper case.</p>

        <!--<input type="submit" value="Insert record" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">-->

<input type="hidden" name="LastNameID" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="Category" value="B" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<input type="submit" id="closebtn" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
</form>
```

This is the insert script in addlastname.php

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO lt_lastnames (LastNameID, LastName, Category) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['LastNameID'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['LastName'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Category'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_vetonline, $vetonline);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $vetonline) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Since this form (addlastname) is loaded into a bootstrap modal, when the submit button is clicked, the page submits to itself and after submit the browser displays the plain external file (addlastname.php).

**What I want**
I want to close the modal on submit and return to the parent file from which it was loaded. Be it students.php or teacher.php or coordinator.php. Moreover I also want to retain the original url with the variables before the form was loaded in the modal. For example: student.php?id=20 or teacher.php?id=123 etc. I want to return to this dynamic url on submit.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Have you considered using ajax to submit your data?

Comment: No. I don't know. How to use AJAX. @Leo Farmer Can you guide me or show me some working code to understand?